# How can I troubleshoot why my PHP script won't work in cron when it does from the command line?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've got a script that calls two functions, A and B, from the same class. A creates an Amazon virtual server and B destroys one, both via shell_exec()'s of Amazon's command line tools. The script, doActions.php, pulls actions from a queue. If the action is "create" it creates an instance; when the action is "destroy" it kills one.

The script works fine to execute both A and B when I execute it from the command line: php script.php.

When I put it on a cron, it runs but only successfully runs the B function. It deletes destroys instances but won't create them.

The point of failure is clearly function B. It chokes at the first and most important shell_exec, returning and echoing nothing.

```
echo $string = shell_exec('/home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/ec2-api-tools/bin/ec2-run-instances ami-23b6534a -k gsg-keypair -z us-east-1a');
```

Unless you know something specific about the way Amazon's command line tools work, please suggest to me reasons why a shell_exec might work in one case and not the other.

Another shell_exec in the same place behaves as expected:

```
echo $string = shell_exec ('echo overflow');
```

My guess is that it has to do something with permissions. But when I have it run `shell_exec('whoami')` it return "root," and when I `su` and run the command it works fine. I'm having a hard time thinking of creative ways to troubleshoot why my PHP script won't work in cron when it does from the command line. Can you suggest some?

Comment: This won't solve your problem directly, but you can also consider using [one of the many PHP implementations of the EC2 API](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.ec2.html) rather than shelling out every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When something runs from the command line but refuses to do so within `cron`, it's often an environment issue (path or some other environment variable that's needed by the code you're running).

For a start you should modify the script to output the current environment (`shell_exec('env')`?) at the very top and examine the output from the command line and cron.

Hopefully, there will be something obvious such as `AMAZON_EC2_VITAL_VAR` but, if not, you should move the cron environment towards your command line one, one variable at a time, until it starts working.

A quick test to ascertain this. From your command line, do:

```
env >/tmp/pax_env.sh
```

Then run your PHP script from a shell script which first executes:

```
. /tmp/pax_env.sh
```

so that the environments are identical.

And keep in mind that `su` on its own doesn't give you the same environment as you'd get from logging in directly as a specific user (`su -` does, I *think*). You may want to check the behaviour for when you log in as root directly.

---

Re your comment:

> Yes, I do believe you've got it. I'm likely going to mark your answer as correct but need you to suffer through a few addendums about your clever solution. First of all, what's the best way to execute the pax_env.sh script? Does shell_exec() work?

Never let it be said I didn't work for my money :-) No. The `shell_exec` will almost certainly be running a sub-shell so the variables would be set *in* that sub-shell but would not affect the PHP parent process.

My advice, if you wanted all those variables set, would be to create a shell-script consisting of all the commands in `/tmp/pax_env.sh` (probably prefixing each with `export`) followed by the command you currently have running in `cron`, something along the lines of:

```
export PATH=.:/usr/bin
export PS1=Urk:
export PS2=MoreUrk:
/home/user/pax/scriptB.php
```

Then run *that* script from `cron` rather than `/home/user/pax/scriptB.php` directly. That will ensure the environment is set up before your PHP code is called.

Astute readers will have noticed the phrase "if you wanted all those variables set" above. I don't personally think it's a good idea to dump *all* your command line variables into the shell script for the `cron` job. I'd prefer to actually find out which ones are needed and only include those. That lessens the pollution your cron job has to run under. For example, it's unlikely that the `PS1/PS2` prompt variables will be required for your PHP script.

If it works, you *can* set all the environment variables - I just prefer the absolute minimum so I don't have to worry too much when things change.

A way of finding out what's needed is to comment out one `export` at a time until your script breaks again. Then you know that variable is needed. Once it works with the maximum amount of `export` statements commented out, you can just delete those commented export statements altogether and what remains, however improbable, must be okay (with apologies to Sir Arthur Conan Doyle).