# Cronjob does not execute command line in perl script

Tags: sql, linux, perl, cron

I am unfamiliar with linux/linux environment so do pardon me if I make any mistakes, do comment to clarify.

I have created a simple perl script. This script creates a sql file and as shown, it would execute the lines in the file to be inserted into the database.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $SQL_COMMAND;
my $HOST = "i";
my $USERNAME = "need";
my $PASSWORD = "help";
my $NOW_TIMESTAMP = strftime '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S', localtime;

open my $out_fh, '>>', "$NOW_TIMESTAMP.sql" or die 'Unable to create sql file';

printf {$out_fh} "INSERT INTO BOL_LOCK.test(name) VALUES ('wow');";

sub insert()
{
    my $SQL_COMMAND = "mysql -u $USERNAME -p'$PASSWORD' ";

    while( my $sql_file = glob '*.sql' )
    {
        my $status = system ( "$SQL_COMMAND < $sql_file" );
        if ( $status == 0 )
        {
           print "pass";
        }
        else
        {
           print "fail";
        }
    }
}

insert();
```

This works if I execute it while I am logged in as a user(I do not have access to Admin). However, when I set a cronjob to run this file let's say at 10.08am by using the line(in `crontab -e`):

```
08 10 * * * perl /opt/lampp/htdocs/otpms/Data_Tsunami/scripts/test.pl > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I know the script is being executed as the sql file is created. However no new rows are inserted into the database after 10.08am. I've searched for solutions and some have suggested using the DBI module but it's not available on the server.

EDIT: Didn't manage to solve it in the end. A root/admin account was used to to execute the script so that "solved" the problem.

Comment: Do you have a reason to avoid the [`DBI` module](http://metacpan.org/module/DBI)?

Comment: Can you change your `printf` to a `print`? The [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) have something interesting to say about using `printf` with a filehandle and without a list.

Comment: @MattJacob: There's no problem with using `printf` with just a format string and no parameters. The "list" that the documentation talks about omitting includes the format, as in `printf FH` which is equivalent to `printf FH $_`, but with a lexical file handle like `printf $fh` Perl interprets as printing to the currently-selected output handle using the stringified file handle `"$fh"` as a format string

Answer (score 2):

First things first, get rid of the `> /dev/null 2>&1` at the end of your `crontab` entry (at least temporarily) so you can actually *see* any errors that may be occurring.

In other words, change it temporarily to something like:

```
08 10 * * * perl /opt/lampp/htdocs/otpms/Data_Tsunami/scripts/test.pl >/tmp/myfile 2>&1
```

Then you can examine the `/tmp/myfile` file to see what's being output.

The most *likely* case is that `mysql` is not actually on the path in your `cron` job, because `cron` itself gives a rather minimal environment.

To fix that problem (assuming that's what it is), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295611/how-can-i-troubleshoot-why-my-php-script-wont-work-in-cron-when-it-does-from-th/3295657#3295657), which gives some guidelines on how best to expand the `cron` environment to give you what you need. That will probably just involve adding the MySQL executable directory to your `PATH` variable.

The other thing you may want to consider is closing the `out_fh` file before trying to pass it to `mysql` - if the buffers haven't been flushed, it may still be an empty file as far as other processes are concerned.

Comment: It says `sh: mysql: command not found
fail` for a couple of times then there's `SQL file size is 0`. The latter is a check I've added to check whether the file size is 0. Not sure why the `command is not found` though. It runs and inserts when I execute the file manually, but not when it's by cronjob. Sorry for the late (to whoever is reading as well).

Comment: @hzq, then it is indeed what I thought. MySQL is not on the path for your cronjob, because `cron` gives you a rather minimal environment. On how to fix, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972690/cannot-get-php-cron-script-to-run/1972763#1972763, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295611/how-can-i-troubleshoot-why-my-php-script-wont-work-in-cron-when-it-does-from-th/3295657#3295657 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068071/include-path-and-cron/1068084#1068084.

Answer (score 0):

> The expression glob(".* *") matches all files in the current working
>   directory.
>   - http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html

you should not rely on the wd in a cron job. If you want to use a glob (or any file operation) with a relative path, set the wd with chdir first.
source: http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=395387

So if your working directory is, for example `/home/user`, you should insert

```
chdir('/home/user/');
```

before the `WHILE`, ie:

```
sub insert()
{
    my $SQL_COMMAND = "mysql -u $USERNAME -p'$PASSWORD' ";

    chdir('/home/user/');

    while( my $sql_file = glob '*.sql' )
    {
...
```

replace `/home/user` with wherever your sql files are being created.

Comment: Even better: don't use `glob` and construct full paths for all files and directories.

Comment: that would be better but my attempt was to answer the person's question most directly `"why doesn't this work?"` rather than to get all didactic.

Comment: Yeah I just want to understand why. I've tried as you suggested but I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do as much processing within Perl as possible. It avoids the overhead of generating a separate shell process and leaves everything under the control of the program so that you can handle any errors much more simply

Database access from Perl is done using the [`DBI` module](http://metacpan.org/module/DBI). This program demonstrates how to achieve what you have written using the `mysql` utility. As you can see it's also much more concise

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $host     = "i";
my $username = "need";
my $password = "help";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=$host", $username, $password);

my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO BOL_LOCK.test(name) VALUES (?)');

my $rv = $insert->execute('wow');

print $rv ? "pass\n" : "fail\n";
```

Comment: The original post says that DBI isn't installed on the server.